# python how to iterate cells in the same column in a CSV file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

Assume I have a csv file with the following columns:

```
system     component    version  otherColumn...

type1         abc          4      
              qwe          5
              asd          6

type2         rty          3

type3         vbn          8
              asd          9
```

I would like to parse the CSV file as dictionary as follows:

```
{
 type1: { abc: 4, qwe: 5,asd: 6}
 type2: { rty: 3}
 type3: { vbn: 8, asd: 9}
}
```

I only want the above 3 columns in the dict. The other columns are not required.

I tried as follows:

```
import csv

dict = {}
f = open("myfile", 'rt')
reader = csv.reader(f)
     for col in row
        if col == 'system':
            //I am stuck here
```

Can someone please assist on how it can be done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
import csv

data = {}
with open("myfile", "rb") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        d = data.setdefault(row["system"], {})
        # Here, you may want to handle invalid values in the version field
        d[row["component"]] = int(row["version"])
```